# Unable to Trigger Mongoose Pre/Post Hook on Document Deletion

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am facing difficulties in implementing pre and post hooks for document deletion in Mongoose. I have tried various approaches, including using `deleteOne`, `deleteMany`, `findOneAndDelete`, and `findOneAndRemove`. I've also explored alternatives like modifying the deleteOne middleware code to first find the document and then use `doc.deleteOne()`, but to no avail.

Here are the details of my implementation:

**Mongoose Schema:**

```
import { Schema, Types } from "mongoose";

export interface IUploadedImage {
  _id?: Types.ObjectId;
  thumbnail?: string;
  medium?: string;
  large?: string;
  original: string;
}

const schema = new Schema<IUploadedImage>({
  _id: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  thumbnail: String,
  medium: String,
  large: String,
  original: { type: String, required: true },
});

export const uploadedImageSchema = schema;
```

**Hooks:**

```
schema.pre("deleteMany", async function () {
  console.log("Doc will be deleted soon");
});

schema.pre("deleteOne", async function () {
  console.log("Doc will be deleted soon");
});

schema.pre("findOneAndDelete", async function () {
  console.log("Doc will be deleted soon");
});

schema.pre("findOneAndRemove", async function () {
  console.log("Doc will be deleted soon");
});
```

**Deletion Code:**

```
import * as middleware from '../../_shared/middleware';

const middlewareOptions: CrudActionOptions = {
    modelName: 'Church',
    paramId: 'churchId',
    ignoreChurchId: true,
    passToNext: false,
    permissionsPath: 'church',
};

router.delete('/:churchId', middleware.crud.deleteOne({ ...middlewareOptions }));
```

**Delete Middleware Code:**

```
export function deleteOne(options: CrudActionOptions) {
  const Model = getModel(options.modelName);

  return async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      const hasPermissions = validatePermissions(options, res, ['delete']);

      if (!hasPermissions) return next(new Error('NoPermission'));

      const deletedItem = await Model.findOneAndDelete(getQueryConditions(req, res, options));
      
      if (!deletedItem) return res.status(404).json({ message: 'Item not found' });

      if (options.assignTo) {
        res.locals[options.assignTo] = deletedItem;
        if (options.passToNext) {
          return next();
        }
      }

      res.status(204).send();
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
}
```

Despite my efforts, the pre hooks do not trigger, and no log is displayed in the console after a document is deleted. I have ensured that the hooks are registered before creating the model, but the issue persists.

I appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this problem. Thank you!

Comment: Which version of Mongoose are you using ?

Comment: Using the 7.5.2 version

Answer (score 0):

all the `pre()` hooks should have `next();` in order to proceed to the next md, in this case, it's your Delete Middleware Code.

Try to modify your pre-hooks to be like this

```
schema.pre("deleteOne", async function (next) {
  console.log("Doc will be deleted soon");
next();
});
```

also, mongoose treats `deleteOne` as a query hook, always try to `console.log(this)` inside the hook to know which type of hook it is.

mongoose documentation says :

> To register deleteOne middleware as document middleware, use
> schema.pre('deleteOne', { document: true, query: false }).

I hope this answer help you.